# Convert PyQt to PIL image

Tags: python, pyqt, python-imaging-library

I have an image in a QImage and I want to process it in PIL before I display it. While the ImageQT class lets me convert a PIL Image to a QImage, there doesn't appear to anything to go from a QImage to a PIL Image.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I convert it from QImage to PIL with this code:

```
img = QImage("/tmp/example.png")
buffer = QBuffer()
buffer.open(QIODevice.ReadWrite)
img.save(buffer, "PNG")

strio = cStringIO.StringIO()
strio.write(buffer.data())
buffer.close()
strio.seek(0)
pil_im = Image.open(strio)
```

I tried many combinations before getting it to work.

Comment: This also works in Python3, just change "cStringIO.StringIO" to "io.BytesIO".

Comment: for PySide2 `5.x`, `buffer.data()` returns a `QByteArray`. If you call `data()` on the `QByteArray` it should give you what you want. Be careful about color channels though if you are using `numpy`.

Answer (score 2):

Another route would be:

1. Load the image data into a numpy array ([example code](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/io/_plugins/pil_plugin.py#L15) using PIL)
2. Manipulate the image using numpy, scipy or scikits.image
3. Load the data into a QImage (example: browse the scikits.image archive (linked in 1) and look on line 45 of qt_plugin.py -- sorry, stackoverflow doesn't allow me to post more links yet)

As Virgil mentions, the data must be 32-bit (or 4-byte) aligned, which means you need to remember to specify the strides in step 3 (as shown in the snippet).

Comment: Can you add the other link yet? (Back when I had that problem, I just posted another answer to hold the second link ;-)

Comment: Sure, here it is: https://github.com/stefanv/scikits.image/blob/master/scikits/image/io/_plugins/qt_plugin.py#L45

Answer (score 2):

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PIL import Image

img = QtGui.QImage(width, height, QImage.Format_RGBA8888)
data = img.constBits().asstring(img.byteCount())
pilimg = Image.frombuffer('RGBA', (img.width(), img.height()), data, 'raw', 'RGBA', 0, 1)
```

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PIL import Image

img = QtGui.QImage("greyScaleImage.png")
bytes = img.bits().asstring(img.numBytes())
pilimg = Image.frombuffer('L', (img.width(), img.height()), bytes, 'raw', 'L', 0, 1)
pilimg.show()
```

Thanks Eli Bendersky, your code was helpful.

Comment: You forgot to add four spaces before each line of code (and put only one newline between lines).

Answer (score 2):

```
#Code for converting grayscale QImage to PIL image

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
qimage1 = QtGui.QImage("t1.png")
bytes=qimage1.bits().asstring(qimage1.numBytes())
from PIL import Image
pilimg = Image.frombuffer("L",(qimage1.width(),qimage1.height()),bytes,'raw', "L", 0, 1)
pilimg.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a QImage into a Python string:

```
>>> image = QImage(256, 256, QImage.Format_ARGB32)
>>> bytes = image.bits().asstring(image.numBytes())
>>> len(bytes)
262144
```

Converting from this to PIL should be easy.

Comment: I dont think that direct image data are compatible between QImage and PIL images. What I found out after some messing around (it bit me): Qt aligns all its lines on 32bit, which means that if the number of bytes per line for image is not divisible by 4, there's going to be crap inserted in the data.

Maybe there's even more gotchas...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer for those using `PySide2 5.x`, the official python wrappings for qt. They should also work for `PyQt 5.x`

I also added to `QImage` to `numpy` that I've used in conjunction with this one. I prefer to use `PIL` dependency, mainly because I don't have to track color channel changes.

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui
from PIL import Image
import io


def qimage_to_pimage(qimage: QtGui.QImage) -> Image:
    """
    Convert qimage to PIL.Image

    Code adapted from SO:
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/1756587/7330813
    """
    bio = io.BytesIO()
    bfr = QtCore.QBuffer()
    bfr.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadWrite)
    qimage.save(bfr, 'PNG')
    bytearr = bfr.data()
    bio.write(bytearr.data())
    bfr.close()
    bio.seek(0)
    img = Image.open(bio)
    return img
```

Here is one to convert `numpy.ndarray` to `QImage`

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageQt
import numpy as np

def array_to_qimage(arr: np.ndarray):
    "Convert numpy array to QImage"
    img = Image.fromarray(arr)
    return ImageQt.ImageQt(img)
```