# How to convert QImage(QPixmap) to PIL Image in Python 3?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, python-imaging-library, pyqt5

I would like to convert a image from QImage or Qpixmap class to PIL Image.
I found this: [Convert PyQt to PIL image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733096/convert-pyqt-to-pil-image)

But it seems to doesn't work in Python3. Is the way to implement this to Pyhton3 or do it more simply using new approaches exist?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit):

> The StringIO and cStringIO modules are gone. Instead, import the io
>   module and use io.StringIO or io.BytesIO for text and data
>   respectively.

So the solution is to do the conversion of `cStringIO.StringIO` to `io.BytesIO`.

PyQt5:

```
import io
from PIL import Image
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage
from PyQt5.QtCore import QBuffer

img = QImage("image.png")
buffer = QBuffer()
buffer.open(QBuffer.ReadWrite)
img.save(buffer, "PNG")
pil_im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(buffer.data()))
pil_im.show()
```

PyQt4:

```
import io
from PIL import Image
from PyQt4.QtGui import QImage
from PyQt4.QtCore import QBuffer

img = QImage("image.png")
buffer = QBuffer()
buffer.open(QBuffer.ReadWrite)
img.save(buffer, "PNG")
pil_im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(buffer.data()))
pil_im.show()
```

Comment: @eyllanesc How would you do it in PyQt4?

Comment: @LironLavi I already showed a code for PyQt4 with python3, for python2 you should use the link shown in the question

Comment: I would also add `buffer.close()` after it is no longer needed.